# Stacked bar chart with an "other" group in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

```
df <- structure(list(type = c("UXR", "UXC", "UXU", "UXM", "WDL", "WEE", 
                                   "WPW", "ZZ3", "WHB", "WMB", "WLH", "ZZ4", "WKB", "AUX", "WMA", 
                                   "WDT", "ZZ0", "WL1", "KTJ", "KTB", "WNC", "WEF", "WGL", "KGA", 
                                   "WGO", "WRA", "KTG", "WAH", "KJA", "KJJ", "ZZ1", "WMM", "KTH", 
                                   "KTP", "WGH", "BMB", "KTN", "WDI", "BWG", "KTK", "WBA", "WPA", 
                                   "KJK", "KKK", "WNF", "KJD", "BLH", "WMF", "KJH", "WGN", "KLA", 
                                   "KNA", "KNE", "WQA", "KFJ", "KTF", "KTL", "NAA", "BAF", "KTA", 
                                   "BVA", "KJM", "WBC", "WCB", "WGK", "AFB", "BNP", "KGD", "KKA", 
                                   "KNB", "KNG", "KQD", "WPQ", "AAF"), n = c(97394L, 25645L, 21627L, 
                                                                             9438L, 1866L, 1039L, 1011L, 961L, 960L, 914L, 880L, 816L, 691L, 
                                                                             594L, 549L, 547L, 529L, 504L, 377L, 364L, 359L, 254L, 246L, 244L, 
                                                                             198L, 193L, 183L, 136L, 116L, 104L, 89L, 87L, 81L, 77L, 77L, 
                                                                             65L, 60L, 58L, 42L, 39L, 39L, 35L, 32L, 29L, 18L, 15L, 12L, 12L, 
                                                                             8L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                             2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                 "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -74L), .Names = c("type", 
                                                                                                                                                                                           "n"))
```

I would like to make a stacked barchart with only the top 4 or 5 counts using ggplot2 and geom_bar with stat="identity". How do I get the categories with a low count as "other"

Comment: A useful tool here would likely be the **forcats** function `fct_lump`.

Comment: @joran: Thanks! I will look at `fact_lump`.